# Почему OutOfMemoryError не ловится?

Tags: android, java

При выполнении:

```
public void tutdb(View v) {
    try {

      Intent intent = new Intent(this, dbtut.class);
      startActivity(intent);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {

        Toast tost = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        tost.show();
        System.gc();
    }

}
```

"!!!" не вылезает, приложение вылетает:
[image]

Что делать (надо как-нибудь суметь открыть dbtut.class)?

p.s. переход происходит на многокартинную страницу, так что если предварительно забить оперативу, то её не хватает

Comment: У вас исчерпалась память, а вы выделяете ещё:

    Toast tost = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    tost.show();

Может, сначала дать пробежаться сборщику мусора? И предварительно убедиться, что вы не храните ссылки на объекты, которые забили память.

Comment: @VladD менять местами пробовал (мусорщика с тостом) - не помогло (без отображения !!!)

> И предварительно убедиться, что вы не храните ссылки на объекты, которые забили память.

Честно говоря без понятия. У меня пользователь нажимает на кнопке, происходит переход на активити с картинками, потом он возвращается по нажатию на бэк баттон, выбирает другую кнопку и т.д. Картинки после захода/выхода остаются в памяти, и я не хочу их удалять от туда, пока память не кончится. Поэтому и пихнул System.gc в try-catch.

Comment: Хорошо, а выполнение хотя бы приходит в ваш catch-блок? Запустите под отладчиком.

---
Ну смотрите. Если у вас, допустим, глобальный массив, содержащий данных на всю свободную память минус 2 байта, то вы вообще ничего не сможете сделать, не удалив лишнее из памяти. Потому что любая операция требует расхода памяти, а у вас этой памяти и нету. Вам **необходимо** освободить ненужные объекты. Какие кнопки при этом нажимает пользователь — второстепенный вопрос.

Comment: не ловится - потому что не там ловишь

Comment: @Gorets а вот это уже интересно. Куда ставить надо? В сам dbtut.java?

Comment: нет, там где ты ловишь не может быть OOM, он возникает, где-то у тебя в работе с картинками (кода нет, стек очень мелкий), тут надо не ловить, а правильно работать с bitmap, делать ему recycle, оптимизировать саму картинку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исключение возникает на 58-й строке в *dlp.app.content.paperplanes.free.lgtut.onCreate*, там и нужно ставить try/catch. Вы не там ловите.

И не забывайте делать *recycle* для ненужных более битмапов, в вашем случае это будет разумно делать в *onDestroy* запускаемой *Activity*.

А вообще, ловить *OutOfMemoryError* - плохая идея, ибо после него вовсе не гарантируется стабильная работа приложения, и когда оно всё же упадёт, попытка понять по стэктрэйсу причину проблемы превратится в увлекательный квест. Надо исправлять, а не ловить.